# Save image file from one server to another repeatedly every x minutes

Tags: php, image, cron, copy, jpeg

What I'm asking for is how to set copy action on PHP server to copy image file from remote server in intervals of x minutes.

Essentially I would like to do:

```
$copy = copy('http://domain.com/image.jpg', '.images/destimg.jpg');
```

With addition that it is done every 5 minutes!
Can it be done without using too much memory? How about cron job? What are your recommendations?

Easiest solution I implemented is like this:

1. create a php file with following code

   ```
   <?php
   /*
    * Copy images from remote server 
    */

   $file = 'http://www.example.com/images/image.jpg';
   $file1 = 'http://www.example.com/images/image1.jpg';
   $file2 = 'http://www.example.com/images/image2.jpg';

   $newfile = '/ABSOLUTE/PATH/WHERE/TO/PUT/FILE/images/image.jpg';
   $newfile1 = '/ABSOLUTE/PATH/WHERE/TO/PUT/FILE/images/image1.jpg';
   $newfile2 = '/ABSOLUTE/PATH/WHERE/TO/PUT/FILE/images/image2.jpg';

   if ( copy($file, $newfile) && copy($file1, $newfile1) && copy($file2, $newfile2)) {
       echo "Copy success!";
       //return;
   } else {
       echo "Copy failed.";
   }
   ?>
   ```
2. Test to see if you are getting Copy success message.
3. Comment out or delete echo and uncomment return, remove else part of the code.
4. Create cron job with command:

   php /ABSOLUTE/PATH/TO/YOUR/PHP/FILE/your-file.php

That is it :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you have ssh access and can set up a `cron` job, then this is fairly simple. You just set up a cron job that uses either `curl` or `wget` to download the image and save it in the appropriate folder. PHP doesn't enter into it.

Using curl, your crontab would look something like:

```
*/5 * * * * curl http://domain.com/image.jpg > /......./images/destimg.jpg
```

This is set to run every 5 minutes. Just make sure to set an absolute path for the image destination.

More on cron jobs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: Tried couple of variations via Webmin module to add chron job.
Using commands:

Comment: Sorry, pressed enter...
Here are my attempts:
'cd /var/www/html/images/; curl -O http://www.example.com/image.jpg' and 'curl -o http://www.example.com/image.jpg /var/www/html/images/image.jpg' both commands seems to be ok, but nothing gets downloaded or saved...

Comment: @ronimarin There was an error in my example, now fixed. There needs to be a > after the URL and prior to the destination.

Comment: Still no luck... (changed source link, image I need to pull is there and I can see it via browser on source server).
Output from command curl http://www.example.com/image.jpg > /var/www/html/images/image.jpg ..

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:05 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:05 --:--:--     0

Comment: cron? really? it's unbelievably complex, no reason to use it if you can write a simple daemon instead...